# finding an element in puppeteer using decendent selector with attributes as inner selectors

Tags: automation, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I have a react application and we inserted "data-test-id" into its main components and also into it's inner components.

so basically to find an element that is inside a component i would like to do something like this:

```
const result1 = await page.$eval('[data-test-id="UpperMenu"] [data-test-id="specificElement"]',
                  elem => elem.textContent);
```

but puppeteer does not find the element.

on the other hand, if I use a simple selector on the child it works perfectly:

```
const result1 = await page.$eval('[data-test-id="UpperMenu"] input',
                  elem => elem.textContent);
```

obviously… i'm pretty new to all the jquery, puppeteer stuff… :-)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to get the element using the `data-test-*` attribute with Puppeteer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a child selector with the id of the parent and the id of the child to find your element:

```
const result1 = await page.$eval("#UpperMenu > #specificElement", elem => elem.textContent);
```

This type of questions you can ask them on CSS tags to have more answers also read the documentation about selectors: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS